# How can view the list of emails from the specific sender containing attachments with a specific file type in Outlook?

Tags: search, outlook.com, attachment

I use the Microsoft Outlook web interface. I tried the following, however it returns emails containing attachments with a different file type, because `*.xlsx`  doesn't only apply to attachment.

[image]

Using `ext:xlsx` has the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Outlook web interface currently offers no way to view the list of emails from the specific sender containing attachments with a specific file type.